# SQL, Grouping together certain results only

Tags: sql, oracle

By using this query...

```
SELECT
    im.spl_instr_code_1 as LW,
    sum(pt.nbr_units/im.std_sub_pack_qty) as "Received Units"
FROM
    prod_trkg_tran pt,
    item_master im,
    po_hdr po
WHERE
    pt.sku_id = im.sku_id AND
    pt.ref_field_2 = po.po_nbr AND
    po.ref_field_2='N' AND
    pt.create_date_time BETWEEN to_date('2015-12-29 06:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND to_date('2015-12-29 14:30:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND
    pt.module_name = 'Receiving' 
GROUP BY
    im.spl_instr_code_1
```

I get a result like this...

```
LW   Received Units
==   ==============
10   6150 
20   3206 
25   1981 
30   15207 
55   11618 
56   10077
```

How would I go about grouping some of the already grouped results even more?
Example... Lets assume I want to group the last 3 results together to get a final result like this...

```
LW          Received Units
==          ==============
10          6150 
20          3206 
25          1981 
NEW_GROUP   36902
```

Comment: What is the logic of grouping `NEW_GROUP` ? Anything `LW` greater than 25?

Comment: Also which DB/Version are you using? Looking at query it looks like Oracle but mention the version too.

Comment: Let's go with grouping LW 30-56

Comment: I believe it is Oracle... not sure the version... Using a proprietary GUI to connect to it.... Also not that familiar with Oracle.

Comment: @G-J please remember to upvote answers that help you and to accept the one that best answers your question.  This helps future users with similar problems more easily find the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to SQL server, but this should work for you:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN im.spl_instr_code_1 < 30 
        THEN im.spli_instr_code_1 
    ELSE    'New_Group' 
    END AS LW
im.spl_instr_code_1 as LW, 
SUM(pt.nbr_units/im.std_sub_pack_qty) AS "Received Units"
FROM prod_trkg_tran pt, item_master im, po_hdr po
WHERE pt.sku_id = im.sku_id 
AND pt.ref_field_2 = po.po_nbr 
AND po.ref_field_2='N'
AND pt.create_date_time between to_date('2015-12-29 06:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') and to_date('2015-12-29 14:30:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
AND pt.module_name = 'Receiving' 
GROUP BY 
    CASE WHEN im.spl_instr_code_1 < 30 
        THEN im.spli_instr_code_1 
        ELSE 'New_Group' 
    END
```

The case statement says to use "im.spl_instr_code_1" when its value is less than 30.  If it is greater than or equal to 30, it uses "New_Group".  You can modify the case logic as needed, and make it as complex as needed.

You could have a case for when it's between 0 and 30, 31-60, over 60, etc., etc.  Just remember to use the SAME logic in the select statement as the group by clause and you should be alright.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle you can use a CTE and build a query on top of it. Something like below. If you want to add further groups, you can use subsequent `union` with appropriate `where` clause. For `>30`, this should work.

```
with table1 as
(
    select im.spl_instr_code_1 as LW, sum(pt.nbr_units/im.std_sub_pack_qty) as "Received Units"
    from prod_trkg_tran pt, item_master im, po_hdr po
    where pt.sku_id = im.sku_id AND pt.ref_field_2 = po.po_nbr AND po.ref_field_2='N'
    AND pt.create_date_time between to_date('2015-12-29 06:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
        and to_date('2015-12-29 14:30:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    and pt.module_name = 'Receiving' 
    group by im.spl_instr_code_1
)
select * from table1
where LW<30
union all
select 'NEW_GROUP' as LW,sum("Received Units") as "Received Units"
from table1
where LW >=30
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  What is the benefit of using subqueries and CTEs instead of using a case statement for the group by clause?

Comment: @StanShaw None. Your approach is better and faster. I just didn't want to touch the existing code. So I took that as starting point and built result on top of it :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I wasn't sure if I was missing something.